# SQL Server: how to drop a schema cascade all its objects?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server: how to drop a schema and cascade the delete operation to all its objects? e.g.,

```
database1
   schema1
   schema2
      table1
      table2
```

Drop schema:

```
drop schema database1.schema2
```

The schema can not be dropped. In Oracle:

```
drop user schema2 cascade
```

How to achieve the same in SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think we can drop the schema without dropping the table where it is referenced. We need to drop the table first including its primary key and foreign key and then we can drop the schema. You can use dynamic SQL to create `DROP TABLE` script of all the tables in your schema.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `DROP TABLE` dynamic SQL query for all the tables under particular schema and then execute it first before dropping `SCHEMA`. Something like below you need to do. Please note that you also need to **drop primary keys and foreign key of the table** before dropping it.

```
DECLARE @SQL        NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Counter    INT
DECLARE @TotalRows  INT

SET @SchemaName = 'DBO'
SET @Counter = 1

SET @SQL='
SELECT ''DROP TABLE '' + S.[Name] + ''.'' + O.[Name] AS DropTableStatement
FROM SYS.OBJECTS AS O INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS AS S ON O.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id]
WHERE O.TYPE = ''U'' AND S.[Name] = ''' + @SchemaName + ''''

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DropStatements

CREATE TABLE #DropStatements
(
    ID                  INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    DropTableStatement  VARCHAR(2000)
)

INSERT INTO #DropStatements
EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(ID) FROM #DropStatements

WHILE @Counter <= @TotalRows
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = DropTableStatement FROM #DropStatements WHERE ID = @Counter

    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END

SET @SQL = N'DROP SCHEMA ' + @SchemaName
PRINT @SQL
EXEC @SQL
```

Comment: @Sunnyday, let me know if you find this helpful.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks!!! I had to make a few changes, but ultimately I have a stored procedure that you pass the schema name to, and it'll then drop all the tables.